# How do I view RSS feed data?

Tags: mac, rss

I have an RSS source link: https://www.zhihu.com/rss
and I want to have a look at its data, so I type the link in the browser (Safari), but I get the error below:

[image]

> **No RSS reader is installed.**
>
> Safari can't open "feed:https://www.zhihu.com/rss" because Safari can't display RSS feeds. You can search the Mac App Store for an RSS app.

How can I have a look at its feed data? I know the data is in an XML-like format, but I don't know how to take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open Terminal
- `cd Documents` (or any other suitable directory)
- `curl -o feed.xml https://www.zhihu.com/rss`
- Use the text editor of your choice to open `feed.xml`